# Where to find old buildings: taverns, castles, cathedrals, etc to visit while in London

Tags: international-travel, london, england

I am traveling to London for 4 days, I don't have a car.

I would like to find some old buildings to visit, perhaps in London, perhaps in another city.

They don't necessarily have to be castles or touristy spots, I just want to get away from modern architecture and into some old parts of town that are made from stone

Is there a place I can take a train to?
I am staying in Vauxhall

I know there is a train to Paris, and I am already taking that, I'm looking for places I can go on a day trip.

Thanks,

Comment: Um ... basically everywhere in central London other than the skyscrapers in the City and scattered modernist developments here and there?

Comment: Is there a nearby town with this kind of appeal?

Comment: Why doesn't London itself count? By the criteria you've given here, you won't be able to walk 200 meters without meeting one or more stone buildings ...

Comment: "Canterbury, a cathedral city in southeast England, was a pilgrimage site in the Middle Ages. Ancient walls, originally built by the Romans, encircle its medieval centre with cobbled streets and timber-framed houses. Canterbury Cathedral, founded 597 A.D., is the headquarters of the Church of England and Anglican Communion, incorporating Gothic and Romanesque elements in its stone carvings and stained-glass windows."

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It appears that you are too early in the planning of your stages for us to be of real help here. Now is the time to be reading guidebooks, tourism websites, and travel blogs for ideas of things to do and places to see, and what you decide on comes down to how you wish to allocate your schedule, interests, and budget.  There is no single right way to "do" a place like London. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] and return when your questions are narrower in scope and better-suited to the format here.

Comment: Oxford, Bath, York, Chester, Warwick, Cambridge, Norwich, Colchester... the list is pretty endless, depending on how far out of London you’re willing to travel.

Answer (score 5):

The [National Heritage List](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/the-list/map-search) map would be a good place to start.  From [their requirements description](https://historicengland.org.uk/listing/what-is-designation/listed-buildings/):

> The general principles are that all buildings built before 1700 which survive in anything like their original condition are likely to be listed, as are most buildings built between 1700 and 1850. Particularly careful selection is required for buildings from the period after 1945. Buildings less than 30 years old are not normally considered to be of special architectural or historic interest because they have yet to stand the test of time.

In central London, you are reasonably likely to be close to any number of listed buildings in most of the standard tourist areas.  Finding a particularly dense cluster of listed sites on the map might satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, London had a fire in 1666 that destroyed a lot of the old stuff. That remaining is listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_buildings_that_survived_the_Great_Fire_of_London See also https://londonist.com/london/history/buildings-that-survived-the-great-fire-of-london and https://londonist.com/2016/08/the-tudor-tube-map

Comment: I'm told they built some more old stuff right after that though :-)

Comment: Yeah, but 350 years old isn't that old in British terms.